# Help with a c++ statement

Tags: c++

The following statement is from WebKit. I am not 100% sure what it means. Any clues?

```
new ((void*)&nullAtom) AtomicString;
```

Comment: Consult your favorite C++ language book about *placement new*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a placement-new.  It means that the AtomicString object will be constructed at the memory location pointed to inside the parentheses (&nullAtom), rather than the usual behavior (constructed on top of a bit of memory taken off of the heap).

Comment: Strictly speaking, you have no idea what it does, because you don't know the class definition of `AtomicString`. What you *do* know is the behaviour of `::new (addr) AtomicString;`.

Answer (score 4):

That's a ["placement new"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10).