# Instantiating a class, using a pointer allocated by malloc()

Tags: c++, c, object, malloc, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++'s “placement new”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new)
>   [Help with a c++ statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576303/help-with-a-c-statement)

I work in a product, where most of the modules have been written in C. Among them, one or two modules are written in C++. I find the below code in a C++ module, which I could not understand what is going on.

```
a = (char *) malloc (size);
b = new (a) MyClass();
```

Could someone explain me how a pointer allocated by malloc is used for new operator? Is it legitimate?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with a c++ statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576303/help-with-a-c-statement), also [What is this second new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960548/what-is-this-second-new), also [Explanation of this new() statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847525/explanation-of-this-new-statement)

Comment: great... I saw the opposite of this, explicit call to destructor, in STL code and was wondering what was that.. 
This is from xmemory.cc file of STL.

     template<class _Ty1> inline
     void _Construct(_Ty1 _FARQ *_Ptr)
 { // construct object at _Ptr with default value
 void _FARQ *_Vptr = _Ptr;

 ::new (_Vptr) _Ty1();
 }

  // TEMPLATE FUNCTION _Destroy
template<class _Ty> inline
 void _Destroy(_Ty _FARQ *_Ptr)
 { // destroy object at _Ptr
 _Ptr->~_Ty();
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b = new (a) MyClass();` is called **placement new** and it constructs new object of type `MyClass` on a pre-allocated memory (memory that pointer `a` points to).

You should also check this question: [What uses are there for "placement new"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/222557/1168156)

Answer (score 2):

new can take parameter, which tells new the starting address of the memory...so what the code is doing is...

```
a = (char *) malloc (size);
```

allocate memory of the new class...

```
b = new (a) MyClass();
```

tell new to use 'a' as the starting address of memory, and initialize the clas at address of 'a' ...

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `new (something) Type` is called placement
new.  Like all `new`, it calls an allocator function, then the
constructor of `Type`.  The allocator function has the signature:

```
    void* operator new( size_t byteCount, something );
```

In other words, whatever you put in the parentheses is passed on as
additional arguments to the `operator new` function.

In addition to the usual `operator new` function, the standard defines
two other `operator new` functions, which take additional arguments:

```
void* operator new( size_t byteCount, std::nothrow_t ) noexcept;
```

and

```
void* operator new( size_t byteCount, void* where ) noexcept;
```

Note that both are `noexcept`.  The first returns a null pointer if
allocation fails (rather than throwing `bad_alloc`), and the second
simply returns `where`.  (The second is also known as placement new.
Which leads to no end of confusion: “placement new” can
refer to any extended new, or to jsut the one which takes a `void*`.)

In your case, the second is the one being used, although I would
seriously question why: if the object type has a destructor, you will
have to do:

```
b->~MyClass();
free( b );
```

to delete it.  (Placement new and explicit delete are usually used in
cases where you want to separate allocation from initialization.  In an
implementation of `std::vector`, for example, where the capacity can be
larger than the size.)  About the only reason for it here that I can see
is that the object must be allocated in C++, but will be deleted in C
(and of course, it has a trivial destructor—otherwise, there's no
way C can correctly delete it).